# php echo not working for strtotime function while assigning it to a javascript variable

Tags: php, jquery

This works fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
    var timeLeft = <?php echo '1279'; ?>;       

    $("#time").text(timeLeft); 
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="time"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but this doesn't

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
         var timeLeft = <?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>;       
         $("#time").text(timeLeft); 
    });
</script>
```

It gives error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < .
It is a php extension file.

Comment: View the generated source to see what PHP is outputting.

Comment: @MrCode, wouldn't a syntax error be fatal and kill the code at the line the error is, preventing you from seeing anything other than the error being output at the HTML line of the syntax error?

Comment: @crypticツ if there was a syntax error or other fatal error, by viewing the source you would see everything before the opening PHP tag. Depending on config, you could also see the error message printed there.

Comment: @MrCode yeah that was what I meant when I was asking. =o)

Comment: It is giving a warning var timeLeft = '<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  strtotime() [<a href='function.strtotime'>function.strtotime</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no DST' instead in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\phpjquery\index.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
1357644612';

Comment: @MrCode, i got it, it was just a warning if i use error_reporting(0) it works. Thanx

Comment: @thewwwdesigners, don't do that, that is just hiding the error which does not fix it. Please see my answer below. You should always have error reporting at its highest when developing otherwise you will not be notified on any errors in your code which will cause you hours of headache and confusion.

Comment: @thewwwdesigners - if you have extra info for the question, it's better to edit the question rather than pasting it into comments; it's a lot more readable that way.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
     var timeLeft = '<?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>';       
     $("#time").text(timeLeft); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: `strtotime()` outputs a timestamp (integer) so no reason to quote it, right?

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
     var timeLeft = '<?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>';       
     $("#time").html(timeLeft); 
});
</script>

Comment: @Sandy this does not explain why example 1 works but example 2 does not. As BOTH are outputting an integer, and that integer is being passed to `text()`. Should both not cause it to error then?

Answer (score 0):

Directly using php in javascript is very dangeorous. Because timetostr may output some warnings about timezone etc and your code will be broken without any visual clue.

In my projects, If I have to use any php output in my javascript, I create hidden divs and access the value from javascript:

```
<div class='hidden' id='values'>
<div class='val-time'><?php echo strtotime("now"); ?></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
         var timeLeft = $("#values .val-time").html();       
         $("#time").text(timeLeft);
    });
</script>
```

So whenever you want to debug your code, simply remove "hidden" class from #values and look at which values are ouputted by PHP.